# I want to send multiple email request at a time using smtp in console application .how I can send bulk email request at a time with using threading

Tags: c#, .net, api

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    Thread T1 = new Thread(delegate ()
    {
            Console.WriteLine("email sent..");
            smtp.Send(msg);
    });
    T1.Start();
}
```

I am trying to send bulk request with multithreading using smtp.Send(msg).

I have tried the code above but I am getting this error

> An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method

How I can resolve this.

Comment: Simple answer is that you will have to use mutliple instances of whatever SMTP client/library you're using. It doesn't semm possible to send multiple emails asynchronously using the same connection to the SMTP server.

Comment: Are you sending _the same_ email to multiple recipients? Or to each one an individual mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using following [client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0). I would recommend you refactor your code like following:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>()
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    task.Add(smtp.SendAsync(msg));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
```

What's the difference?

Using tasks will use Threads in the background but will take care of all the thread scheduling and cleanup. c# [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) is the way to go if you want to add parallelism and concurrency to your application applications (I stole that line from above link)

Taking into account @phuzi comment on your question it can be that you need to instantiate a client inside your for loop.

Bare in mind that this will use await for you'll have to add async to your function signature.

Comment: I have just made a simple SMTP client which sends emails from the program. It is a console application and can only send one email through the server at a time. This is very slow and I need to send multiple emails through my client at the same time.

Comment: Well in that case I think most of my answer can be discarded :D. But I guess it will be best to share some of that code.

Comment: Just for the record: `async` is _not_ part of the signature.

Comment: @Fildor function definition then?

Comment: @JochemVanHespen Nevermind. I was just nitpicking. I am fine with your answer, just wanted to clearify that little but seemingly common misconception. But I think it is clear what you meant.